# Is there a way to do xor with two node type of class (in which one of them can be None)

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, next=None):
        self.data = data
        self.npx = None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def XOR(self, a, b):
        return a ^ b


    def insert(self, data):

        new_node = Node(data)
        new_node.npx = self.head
        if self.head is not None:
            self.head.npx = self.XOR(new_node, self.head.npx)
            print(self.head.npx)
        self.head = new_node



    def printList(self):
        curr = self.head
        prev = None

        print("Following are the nodes of Linked List")
        while(curr):
            print(curr.data)
            next = self.XOR(prev, curr.npx)
            prev = curr
            curr = next



if __name__ == "__main__":
    llist = LinkedList()
    llist.insert(10)
    llist.insert(20)
    llist.insert(30)
    llist.insert(40)

    llist.printList()
```

This is my code I am getting error 
unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'Node' and 'NoneType'

My task is to convert a singly linked list to xor linked list 
for ref:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/xor-linked-list-a-memory-efficient-doubly-linked-list-set-2/

This is the link
Please help to solve this I have done maximum part but lagging at small place of how to do xor for the code

Comment: the problem is with you `XOR()` function. In link you shared they converting nodes to `uintptr_t` you missed this condition

Comment: this will help https://github.com/subsr97/daily-coding-problem/blob/master/challenges/xor-linked-list.py

Answer (score 1):

*I am getting error unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'Node' and 'NoneType'*

As you do:

```
def XOR(self, a, b):
    return a ^ b
```

You must use arguments supporting `^`, as above error suggest you use object of your own class `Node` as `a`, so you should provide `Node` with proper so-called [magic method](https://rszalski.github.io/magicmethods/) - in this case it is `__xor__` which:

> `__xor__(self, other)`
>       Implements bitwise xor using the ^ operator.

Comment: can you help me with syntax I am not sure as its giving me error
I wrote it this way but still confused with syntax though


def XOR(self, a, b):
        return a.__xor__(b)

Is it correct